# Correct preposition for geographical location

Tags: word-usage

I'm working in the United Arab Emirates. I want to know how to make a sentence describing my (city) location with the correct preposition.

For example, should I write:

- I'm in Dubai
- I'm on Dubai
- I'm at Dubai.

Which one is correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of 'difference between 'at' and 'in' when specifying location'.

Answer (score 0):

In English, when describing geographical location in a specifically named city, state, or country, we use the preposition "in."

1. I'm in Dubai. (city)
2. I'm in Florida. (state)
3. I'm in Australia. (country)

Questions of this nature are considered "general-learning questions" and are better-suited to https://ell.stackexchange.com/.

Please post future questions like the one above to that (ELL) site, as their community is more focused on helping students and language learners.

Best of luck in your studies.